# Missing comma error error inserting sql through access 2010 vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, oracle11g, ms-access-2007

Having the weirdest problem ever. I do have an sql insert statement, that properly works in sql. When i put that sql into vba it works very good from my pc. However, it does not work and shows sql error: missing comma. Where can be the problem??? I use Access 2010 plus, others use same Access version and having same ODB connections (DSN servers) . Some code example:

```
   sql = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
        "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
        "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
        "(HOST= ODB)(PORT=1520))" & _
        "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ABTL))); uid=IN; pwd=XXX;"

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
  con.Open sql

        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rst.EOF

insetSQL = con.Execute(" INSERT INTO STOCK (PNM_AUTO_KEY, PN, DESCRIPTION, HISTORICAL_FLAG, qty_oh, qty_adj, qty_available, CTRL_NUMBER, CTRL_ID, receiver_number, rec_date, serial_number,pcc_auto_key, cnc_auto_key, loc_auto_key, whs_auto_key, unit_cost, adj_cost, stc_auto_key, visible_mkt, remarks, ifc_auto_key, exp_date, unit_price, tagged_by, tag_date, owner, PART_CERT_NUMBER,ORIGINAL_PO_NUMBER, SHELF_LIFE, CTS_AUTO_KEY, MFG_LOT_NUM, AIRWAY_BILL )" & _
                                    "  VALUES ( " & rst![minimumas] & ", '" & rst![pn] & "', '" & "FROM_SCRIPT" & "', '" & "F" & "'," & rst![qty_oh] & "," & rst![qty_oh] & "," & rst![qty_oh] & "," & "G_STM_CTRL_NUMBER.nextval" & "," & "1" & ", '" & rst![receiver_number] & "', " & " TO_DATE('" & rst![rec_date] & "','YYYY-MM-DD'), '" & rst![serial_number] & "'," & rst![pcc_auto_key] & "," & rst![cnc_auto_key] & "," & rst![loc_auto_key] & "," & rst![whs_auto_key] & "," & rst![unit_cost] & "," & rst![unit_cost] & "," & "1" & ",'" & "T" & "', '" & rst![remarks] & "'," & _
                                      "1" & ", " & " TO_DATE('" & rst![exp_date] & "','YYYY-MM-DD'), " & "0" & ",'" & rst![TAGGED_BY] & "', " & " TO_DATE('" & rst![tag_date] & "','YYYY-MM-DD'), '" & "" & "', '" & rst![PART_CERT_NUMBER] & "', '" & rst![ORIGINAL_PO_NUMBER] & "', '" & rst![SHELF_LIFE] & "', " & rst![CERT_SOURCE] & ", '" & rst![MFG_LOT_NUM] & "', '" & rst![AIRWAY_BILL] & "'" & " )")

Loop
```

Comment: You say it works very good in VBA but has an error.  Does it work "except when" you do something?

Comment: And can you post what it looks like as a string. So we can see if any of the variables are adding something causing an issue?

Comment: It looks very long. I think you should try to add line breaks/line continuation.

Comment: Hello, that vba code works well on my machine, but on others computers it does not work, giving oracle error-missing comma. So if values would be wrong here, it would not be working also on my machine. Even tried to change computer regional settings but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It might be that one of the rescordset fields that is a string data type, has a value that contains a comma but you have not treated it as string.

eg

```
VALUES ( " & rst![minimumas] & ",
```

For the above code to work minimumas CANNOT contain any commas.

Are you certain that all the string fields int he recordset have been appended to the SQL string with a ' around them.

We need to see the sql string is created which then causes the error.  Please provide this as requested.

=========================================================

PART 2  Viewing the SQL causing the error

replace

```
 insetSQL = con.Execute(
```

with 
    on error resume next 
    strMySQl = the string currently used in the execute statement
    insetSQL = con.Execute(strMySQl)
    if err.number <> 0 then
        stop
        debug.print err.number, err.description
        debug.print strMySQl
    end if

then post the sql string that is printed in the immediate window to this site.

I would also suggest that you compare the SQL string generated on your machine with the other machines - just in case something weird is happening.

Comment: Hello, that vba code works well on my machine, but on others computers it does not work, giving oracle error-missing comma. So if values would be wrong here, it would not be working also on my machine. Even tried to change computer regional settings but it did not work

Comment: Do the other machines have a reference to the same ADO library? Do the other machine use the saem oracle account?  Are the oracle settings the same?  Is the SQl text generated the same?  (Can you post the SQl text that is created.)

Comment: SQL text is posted at the top which i use to insert extra column, machines having same ADO library & yes use same oracle account. Could it be because of access versions? Despite we do have installed Office 2010 plus, but when i open access it shows on my pc Access 2007-2010, while for others shows Access 2010

Comment: The access version might be the issue, but before further consideration I think furtehr investigation can be done - see part 2 of my answer

Comment: Found a problem!!! In DSN options there are also regional settings, where should determine decimal symbol for float numbers. As regional setings of each pc could be different, so changing regional settings in dsn would solve  a problem;)

Comment: Ah. Worth knowing. Please post the code you used to fix this, so I can learn from it!

Comment: When you go  to ODBC data source, and press configure User DSN, there is last step where you can put a tick on setting "use regional settings when outputting currency,numbers dates and times".

Comment: You might like to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690545(v=vs.85).aspx